# Building chromium fails with strange error

Tags: android, browser, chromium

I'm trying out building chromium by following [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md) I strictly followed tutorial steps.

Every step is performed. then when  I run `autoninja -C out/Default chrome_public_apk`, it fails.
Please see the error logs

Please note - I'm using :
python 3.7.5
ubuntu 18.04.5

I also tried building it from scratch but the same thing happens..

Anyone please guild me

Error log :

```
FAILED: gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk__compile_resources.srcjar obj/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.ap_ obj/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.ap_.info gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk__compile_resources_R.txt obj/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.resources.proguard.txt gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk__compile_resources.resource_ids 


python3 
../../build/android/gyp/compile_resources.py 
--include-resources=@FileArg\(gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.build_config.json:android:sdk_jars\) 
--aapt2-path ../../third_party/android_build_tools/aapt2/aapt2 
--dependencies-res-zips=@FileArg\(gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.build_config.json:deps_info:dependency_zips\) 
--extra-res-packages=@FileArg\(gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.build_config.json:deps_info:extra_package_names\) 
--extra-main-r-text-files=@FileArg\(gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.build_config.json:deps_info:extra_main_r_text_files\) 
--min-sdk-version=23 
--target-sdk-version=31 
--webp-cache-dir=obj/android-webp-cache 
--android-manifest gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk_manifest/AndroidManifest.xml 
--srcjar-out gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk__compile_resources.srcjar 
--version-code 489609200 
--version-name 100.0.4896.92 
--arsc-path obj/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.ap_ 
--info-path obj/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.ap_.info 
--debuggable 
--r-text-out gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk__compile_resources_R.txt 
--shared-resources 
--dependencies-res-zip-overlays=@FileArg\(gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.build_config.json:deps_info:dependency_zip_overlays\) 
--proguard-file obj/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk.resources.proguard.txt 
--locale-allowlist=\[\"af\",\ \"am\",\ \"ar\",\ \"as\",\ \"az\",\ \"be\",\ \"bg\",\ \"bn\",\ \"bs\",\ \"ca\",\ \"cs\",\ \"da\",\ \"de\",\ \"el\",\ \"en-GB\",\ \"en-US\",\ \"es\",\ \"es-419\",\ \"et\",\ \"eu\",\ \"fa\",\ \"fi\",\ \"fil\",\ \"fr\",\ \"fr-CA\",\ \"gl\",\ \"gu\",\ \"he\",\ \"hi\",\ \"hr\",\ \"hu\",\ \"hy\",\ \"id\",\ \"is\",\ \"it\",\ \"ja\",\ \"ka\",\ \"kk\",\ \"km\",\ \"kn\",\ \"ko\",\ \"ky\",\ \"lo\",\ \"lt\",\ \"lv\",\ \"mk\",\ \"ml\",\ \"mn\",\ \"mr\",\ \"ms\",\ \"my\",\ \"nb\",\ \"ne\",\ \"nl\",\ \"or\",\ \"pa\",\ \"pl\",\ \"pt-BR\",\ \"pt-PT\",\ \"ro\",\ \"ru\",\ \"si\",\ \"sk\",\ \"sl\",\ \"sq\",\ \"sr\",\ \"sr-Latn\",\ \"sv\",\ \"sw\",\ \"ta\",\ \"te\",\ \"th\",\ \"tr\",\ \"uk\",\ \"ur\",\ \"uz\",\ \"vi\",\ \"zh-CN\",\ \"zh-HK\",\ \"zh-TW\",\ \"zu\",\ \"ar-XB\",\ \"en-XA\"\] 
--resource-exclusion-regex=drawable\[\^/\]\*-xxxhdpi\|-watch\\b\|-ldpi\\b\|com_google_android_material.\*values-small\|com_google_android_material.\*-\(w480dp-port\|w360dp-port\|h480dp-land\|h360dp-land\)\|com_google_android_material.\*/layout\|com_google_android_material.\*/color.\*\(calendar_\|bottom_nav_\|slider_\)\|com_google_android_material.\*/drawable.\*design_snackbar\|com_google_android_material.\*/xml.\*badge_ 
--resource-exclusion-exceptions=\[\"\*shadow\*\",\ \"\*.9.\*\",\ \"\*ic_group_\*\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*/design_text_\*\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*/text_\*\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*/design_layout_tab_\*\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*/layout/m3_auto_complete_simple_item.xml\"\] 
--values-filter-rules=\[\"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Bb\]adge\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Bb\]ottomNavigation\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Bb\]ottomSheet\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Bb\]uttonToggleGroup\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Cc\]alendar\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:design_snackbar\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Ff\]loatingActionButton\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Mm\]aterialAlertDialog\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:mtrl_alert\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:mtrl_slider\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Nn\]avigationView\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Pp\]icker\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Ss\]nackbar\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Ss\]lider\",\ \"\*com_google_android_material\*:\[Tt\]oolbarLayout\"\] 
--emit-ids-out=gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk__compile_resources.resource_ids 
--depfile gen/android_webview/system_webview_no_weblayer_apk__compile_resources.d
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (exit_code=)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with python 3.7.3

The problem come from this line `assert exit_code == 0, f'aapt2 link cmd failed with {exit_code=}'` in `./build/android/gyp/compile_resources.py` that is a new python 3.8 syntax [Python 3.8 whatsnew](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging).

I updated `python3` with the last version (3.10 currently), and it works !